# How to use specific verion of nixpkgs (on macOS)?

Tags: nixos, nix, nixpkgs

How can I point my nix installation (on macOS) to a specific version of nixpkgs? I'm trying to ensure that my home and office computers always use the same versions of all packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can pin the nixpkgs version like shown in the [wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/FAQ/Pinning_Nixpkgs)

```
import (builtins.fetchTarball {
  # Descriptive name to make the store path easier to identify
  name = "nixos-unstable-2018-09-12";
  # Commit hash for nixos-unstable as of 2018-09-12
  url = "https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs/archive/ca2ba44cab47767c8127d1c8633e2b581644eb8f.tar.gz";
  # Hash obtained using `nix-prefetch-url --unpack <url>`
  sha256 = "1jg7g6cfpw8qvma0y19kwyp549k1qyf11a5sg6hvn6awvmkny47v";
}) {}
```